# SWIFT - mailComposeDelegate not called : cancel of MFMailComposeViewController doesn't work

Tags: swift, delegates, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

On the same viewcontroller, we can send an email or a text message to send an information to a friend.
The text message in app fully works. But for the email, the email app opens inside my app with all the informations I asked to write but it's impossible to dismiss it by pushing cancel, nothing happens.
I tried mc.mailComposeDelegate = self or mc.delegate = self and MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate is at the top too.
I looked everything on internet, I didn't find any explanation. 
mailComposeController is never called!
Do you have any idea ?

```
class inviteAFriendViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func emailButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    sendEmail()
}

func sendEmail() {
    let emailTitle = "text"
    let messageBody = "text"
    let toRecipents = [""]

    let mc = MFMailComposeViewController()

    //mc.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mc.delegate = self

    mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
    mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
    mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)

    presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mailComposeController(controller2: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
        print("Mail cancelled")
        controller2.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved.rawValue:
        print("Mail saved")
        controller2.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    case MFMailComposeResultSent.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent")
        controller2.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent failure.")
        controller2.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    default:
        break
    }
    controller2.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got it working without any problems, but my delegate method looks a little bit different to yours:

```
func mailComposeController(controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error:NSError?) {
    switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
        print("Mail cancelled")
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved.rawValue:
        print("Mail saved")
    case MFMailComposeResultSent.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent")
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent failure: %@", [error.localizedDescription])
    default:
        break
    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

you may try this one.

And you need to set
`mc.mailComposeDelegate = self`
and not the
`mc.delegate = self`

Comment: Oh my god it works, I don't know who you are but thank you 1000 times! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 10):

First of all use

```
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
```

instead of

```
mc.delegate = self
```

Moreover, in case of **Swift 3**, delegate method is somehow updated which is:

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?){
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For **Swift 4**:

```
switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:
        print("Mail cancelled")
    case MFMailComposeResult.saved.rawValue:
        print("Mail saved")
    case MFMailComposeResult.sent.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent")
    case MFMailComposeResult.failed.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent failure: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    default:
        break
    }
```